# Two Way Binding with Ref in Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, two-way-binding

I'm new to VUE and trying to learn composition API.

I'm trying to write a simple two-way binding for a text box, but the value under the {{xyz}} does not update, am I doing something wrong?

I believe for Vue2 it was just having a v-bind and {{}} for this.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    Original Text Box
    <textBox :value="text"></textBox>

    Two Way Binding:
    {{ text }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import textBox from '../src/components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HomePage',
  components: {
    textBox
  },

  setup() {
    const text = ref('Inital Value')
    return { text }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

HellowWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="props.value"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TEXTBOX',
  props: { value: String },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.value)
    
    return { props }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Output:
When the app loads

[image: When the app loads]

After updating the text value:

[image]

Comment: props are only meant to be used for [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow), this is no different from Vue 2. In your case instead of `v-model` you should use `v-bind` on the textarea with an @input emit and have the parent mutate the original value. The new value set by the parent will then immediately flow back to the child and reactively update

Comment: @yoduh when I emit from the child component  @input="$emit('updateTextvalue', $event.target.value)" and try to update the variable in parent, using text.value = payload I get warning: [Vue warn] Set operation on key "value" failed: target is readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `v-model` and `modelValue` for the two-way binding.
2. Don't use `props` for two-way binding, since they are readonly.
3. Check the Vue Docs [Component v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) to understand how `v-model` two-way binding works with components.
4. Do not `return { props }` from `setup()`

Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const TextBox = {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  template: `<div>
    Original Text Box <br/>
    <textarea :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"></textarea><br/>
    Two Way Binding:<br/>
    {{ modelValue }}
  </div>`
}

const App = { 
  components: { TextBox },
  setup() {
    const text = ref('Inital Value')
    return { text }
  }  
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>  
  <text-box v-model="text"></tetx-box> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Looks like I'll have to learn a lot more about Vue. Especially the emits too.